# How to allow others to embed my django form to their website?

Tags: python, django, forms, iframe, embed

I have a django web app where user can fill up a form (like a survey) and the form submission is saved on my database. You can check out the form generated by django here: http://raktim.pythonanywhere.com/form-view/2

Now I want others to be able to embed this form to their website.
How do i do this?

For example, in case of google form, we can create a form. Then get an embed link with iframe tags which allow us to show this google form to our website like below:

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSePf2s4UajXzbig7GO2gaXSbV0YFP1qVnDUmytMW2v6i58kwQ/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="382" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>`

How can I do that with a django form?

Apparently simply passing the url of the form page in the src of iframe parameters doesn’t do the trick. Can you anyone please guide me with an example?